# R igraph iterate through edge list and get attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to write an efficient way to print out the edges between two groups. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to get any information from the edge when I am iterating through the edges below, thanks!

```
myG <- erdos.renyi.game(100, 10/100)

E(myG)$weight <- runif(ecount(myG))

V(myG)$group <- ifelse(runif(100)>0.5,1,2)
V(myG)$origIndex <- seq(1,vcount(myG))
V(myG)$label <- paste(sample(LETTERS,vcount(myG), replace=TRUE),     sample(LETTERS,vcount(myG), replace=TRUE),sample(LETTERS,vcount(myG), replace=TRUE),sep="-")

indices1 <- which(V(myG)$group == 1)
indices2 <- which(V(myG)$group == 2)
edgeIDsOfAllBetween <- myG[[indices1, indices2, edges=TRUE]]

uniqueEdgeIDs <- unique(unlist(edgeIDsOfAllBetween))
edgeList <- E(myG)[uniqueEdgeIDs] 
rows <- length(edgeList)

if(rows>0){
  for(r in 1:rows){

    edgeIndex <- edgeList[r]  #how to get the original index??
    weight <- get.edge.attribute(myG, "weight", index= edgeIndex)
    n1Index <- edgeList[r,1] #how to get the index of the first vertex????
    n2Index <- edgeList[r,2] #how to get the index of the second vertex????
    n1IndexisIN1 <- n1Index %in% indices1

    n1 <- get.vertex.attribute(myG,"label",index = n1Index)
    n2 <- get.vertex.attribute(myG,"label",index = n2Index)

    if(n1IndexisIN1){
      n1 <- paste("group1_",n1,sep="")
      n2 <- paste("group2_",n2,sep="")
    }else{
      n1 <- paste("group2_",n1,sep="")
      n2 <- paste("group1_",n2,sep="")
    }

    print(paste(n1, " ", n2, "  weight: ", weight, sep=""))
  }
}
```

Update:
Is there a faster way than converting to a data.frame?:

```
MyEdges <- as.data.frame(get.edgelist(myG))
MyEdges$origindex <- seq(1, ecount(myG))
MyEdges <- subset(MyEdges, origindex %in% uniqueEdgeIDs )

rows <- nrow(MyEdges)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what `edgeList` is and how it is accessed.

You try and iterate over it:

```
for(r in 1:rows){
    edgeIndex <- edgeList[r]
```

but that extracts the edges themselves, not the index:

```
> edgeList[1]
Edge sequence:
    e       
e [1] 3 -- 1
```

but that's not even the first edge in the edge list! Its actually edge number 1 in the graph!

I suspect you just want to iterate over the edgelist itself:

```
> for(edge in edgeList){
+ print(edge)
+ }
[1] 57
[1] 272
[1] 1
[1] 7
```

These are possibly the edge indices you are looking for.

```
> E(myG)[57]
Edge sequence:
     e         
e [57] 34 --  2
> V(myG)[34]$group
[1] 2
> V(myG)[2]$group
[1] 1
```

A simple loop over those edges, getting the vertices for the edge and printing out the two groups is then this, which should print out 1 and 2 (or 2 and 1) each time:

```
> for(edge in edgeList){
 verts = get.edge(myG,edge)
 print(V(myG)[verts[1]]$group) ; print(V(myG)[verts[2]]$group)
 }
```